# Free Camping in Ise, Japan

Tags: japan, camping

I'm planning a month-long trip in Japan in November and I'm trying to save money the best I can. I love free camping, too, so that sounds like a double-win.
I'd like to know if anyone has experience of free camping in the Ise area, if there are woods near the outer or inner shirnes or places I can reach easily and safely camp.

Comment: "Free camping" is illegal in Japan.

Comment: Do you know how cold it is in Japan in November? How are you going to carry all that you need for free camping?